# Getting System.InvalidOperationException in nested method evan after calling the BeginTransaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a method like below code. I pass a `SqlConnection` and a `Transaction` to the nested methods.

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> M(Model model, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        SqlTransaction transaction = null)
{
     IdentityResult result;
     using (transaction = _sqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
     {
         try
         {
            result = await M1(_sqlConnection,model, cancellationToken, transaction);
            if (result.Succeeded) 
            {
                 result = await M2(_sqlConnection,model,cancellationToken, transaction);
            }
            transaction.Commit();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             transaction.Rollback();
             result = GeneralErrors.Failed;
         }
   }
   return result;
}
```

When compiler comes to here:

```
 internal async Task<IdentityResult> M1(SqlConnection connection,Model model,CancellationToken cancellationToken,  SqlTransaction transaction = null)
 {
     using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(query.Query,transaction)) // Error
     {
          //...
     }
  }
```

I get this error when I call `QueryMultiple` method of Dapper.net:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.'

How can I find out where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
connection.QueryMultiple(query.Query,transaction)
```

you actually use following overload of `QueryMultiple` extension method:

```
GridReader QueryMultiple(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null);
```

As you see, second `transaction` parameter that you pass to `QueryMultiple` call is not considered as transaction object, but as `param` for the query.

To fix this, either name `transaction` param explicitly:

```
using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(query.Query, transaction: transaction))
```

or explicitly pass `null` value for `param` argument:

```
using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(query.Query, null, transaction))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had done this, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Hm, strange. Could you please share updated call to `QueryMultiple`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not at work at the moment. But I clearly know that I did the same.

Comment: When you'll be at work, please share the latest version of your code. I have found the same issue in Dapper repository with this fix suggested - https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/713

Comment: Ok sure, Thanks.

Comment: Hi again @CodeFuller, this is exactly my code: using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(query.Query,
            transaction:transaction))

Comment: That's weird. I have reproduced your problem with the `QueryMultiple` as it's specified in the question, but the problem has gone when I used named `transaction` parameter. Are you sure you are not using some outdated version of the assembly? Try debugging your code and make sure the `QueryMultiple` is executed as you specified it in above comment.